# Passing in parameters for pug templates inside pug file

Tags: javascript, html, pug

Is it possible to pass in parameter for `include`ed pug files inside the parent pug file. For example if I have a child template `example.pug`:

```
p #{name}'s Pug source code!
```

And a parent `parent.pug`

```
h1
| Hello world
include example.pug
```

It would be nice to do something like

```
h1
| Hello world
include example.pug {name1}
include exmaple.pug {name2}
```

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rewrite your include as a mixin, which accepts parameters.

**mixins.pug**

```
mixin person(name)
  p #{name}'s Pug source code!
```

**parent.pug**

```
include mixins.pug

h1 Hello world

+person('Kay')
+person('Jamal')
```

See the [pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html) for more info.